# How can I append to an empty JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

```
  var kids = [{}];
  i = 0;
  while (i++ !== count) {
    child = {
      value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
      children: addChildren(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
    };
    kids.push(child);
    console.log( kids );
  }
```

The problem with this is the `kids` object has an empty first element. How can I circumvent it? If I don't declare it as a JSON object, I can't access the `push` element.

Thanks

Comment: Where does the JSON part come in?  And `push` is a method on Javascript arrays, not on Javascript objects.

Comment: +1 to Cheeso. "JSON" is such an overused term. In fact the only proper use of the term "JSON object" is when referring to the object JSON in ECMAScript 5.  IMHO the proper thing to say for what most people mean would be "JSON string".

Comment: A kitten dies every time somebody says "JSON object" or has a variable called "json" that contains parsed data.

Comment: _"The problem with this is the kids object has an empty first element."_ - `kids` is an _array_, and if you don't want the first element to be an empty object why on earth are _you_ putting an empty object there? _Please_ rephrase your question to make it clearer what you are trying to do. Give a concrete example of your desired output. You don't seem to understand the difference between an array and an object (and as the others pointed out you don't seem to know what JSON is either). Help us to help you...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just declare kids as an empty array:

```
var kids = [];
```

Comment: Sounds like he wants to encode it as JSON, which means he needs an array inside a JavaScript object.

Comment: Chris is correct (+1) except that in his comment he just killed another kitten (as per Ates Goral's comment above). As for what Shamoon (OP) wants, I don't think he or she has managed to explain that yet.

Comment: Hunh. Learn something new every day. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to end up with a JavaScript object containing several instances of objects that have two keys `value` and `children`.  It would seem an array is the best choice (which Khnle's and Chris's answers give you):

```
[{"value":2,"children":3}, {"value":12,"children":9}, {"value":20,"children":13}]
```

In your comment to one of the answers, however, you said that you did not want an array. One way to do this is to wrap it, as in Jergason's answer:

```
{
    "children": [
        {"value":2,"children":3}, 
        {"value":12,"children":9}, 
        {"value":20,"children":13}
    ]
}
```

Your question seemed to say that you like arrays because you get the `push` operation, but you would like to avoid them completely.  The only way to **avoid arrays completely** is to tag each object with its own unique key.  If indeed this is what you want, it would look like this:

```
{
    "child0":{"value":2,"children":3}, 
    "child1":{"value":12,"children":9}, 
    "child2":{"value":20,"children":13}
}
```

This is not hard to do; just replace `kids.push(child)` with `kids["child" + i] = child`.

Make sure this is really what you want, though, because this collection of children really seems to scream "array"! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could just have your object contain an empty array.

```
var obj = { "children": [] };
// Your looping code here
obj.children.push(child);
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work. This will make my key `children`, but I'll lose `value`, won't I?

Comment: Nope. You would get at the `child` object by doing `obj.children[0]` and could access the `children` or the `value` by `obj.children[0].children` or `obj.children[0].value`

Answer (score 0):

With some slight changes (add var for local variable):

```
var kids = []; //Note this line
var i = 0; //index counter most likely needs to be local
while (i++ !== count) {
    var child = {
       value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
       children: addChildren(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
    };
    kids.push(child);
    console.log(kids);
 }
```

I think that's what you would want.

Update: Your requirement is rather odd.  You can do this:

```
 var kids = [{}]; //Note this line
 delete kids[0];
 var i = 0; //index counter most likely needs to be local
 while (i++ !== count) {
    var child = {
       value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
       children: addChildren(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
    };
    kids.push(child);
    console.log(kids);
 }
```

or

```
 var kids = [{
       value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
       children: addChildren(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
 }];
 var i = 1; //1 less iteration than previous
 while (i++ !== count) {
    var child = {
       value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
       children: addChildren(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
    };
    kids.push(child);
    console.log(kids);
 }
```

That would satisfy your requirement, but what I show originally is still, I think, what you want.

Comment: That makes `kids` an array. I need it to be JSON all the way through